# Nginx - location with root in other directory and PHP

Tags: php, nginx, nginx-location

I tried to set a location similar as "Apache Alias" with Nginx but I don't able to process PHP script in this folder.

Here is my folder structure (for Dev environment):

```
/var/www
+-  dev/public/ <-- This is my normal Web root : "/"
|   +- assets/
|   |  +- app.css
|   |  +- app.js
|   |
|   +-  index.php
|   +-  favicon.png
|    
+-  cut/public/ <-- This must like an "Apache Alias" : "/cut"
    +- assets/
    |  +- app.css
    |  +- app.js
    |
    +-  index.php
    +-  other_other_file.php (why not)
```

I've tried different solutions but none of them are working.

Here is my best Nginx configuration :

```
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name _;
    root  /var/www/dev/public/;
    index index.php index.html;
    autoindex on;

    # Logs
    rewrite_log on;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    # Serving files
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }

    location /cut {
        root /var/www/cut/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php;
    }

    # PHP
    location @php {
        rewrite ^(.*)/?$ /index.php$is_args$args last;
    }

    location ~* \.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass  php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

With this one, all the content of my `cut/public/` folder is redirected to the `dev/public/index.php` and interpreted (cause of `try_file`, I presume).

That is why your help would be welcome.

**Final Solution**

After the answer of @richard-smith, here's the implemented solution :

```
server {
    listen   80;

    server_name _;
    root  /var/www/dev/public/;
    index index.php index.html;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location ^~ /cut {
        rewrite ^/cut/?(.*)$ /cut/public/$1 last;
    }

    location ^~ /cut/public {
        root /var/www/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /cut/index.php$is_args$args;

        location ~* \.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_pass  php:9000;
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
            fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~* \.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass  php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $document_root;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Running two PHP applications side-by-side, you either need a common document root, or you need two `location ~* \.php` (or similar) blocks to ensure the correct `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is sent to the fastcgi backend.

Use nested `location` blocks to isolate the `/cut` subdirectory, and use the `^~` modifier at the top level to avoid other top level regular expression `location` blocks from interfering (see [this documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location)).

The `alias` directive (see [this documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias)) is used to map `/cut` to `/var/www/cut/public`. The `root` directive can only concatenate, which would make `/var/www/cut/public/cut` (which you do not want).

However, I would not recommend using the `alias` directive with the `try_files` directive because of [this long term issue](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97).

So, a solution would be to silently rewrite `/cut` to `/cut/public` and use a value of `root /var/www`.

For example:

```
location ^~ /cut {
    rewrite ^/cut(.*)$ /cut/public$1 last;
}
location ^~ /cut/public {
    root /var/www;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /cut/index.php$is_args$args;

    location ~* \.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass  php:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Mh, I'try this but what about non php files in `cut/public` ? Will the `try_file` work (because the root is now `/var/www` and not `/var/www/cut/public`) ?

Comment: Yes. The URI to static files is `/cut/assets/app.js`, which is silently changed to `/cut/public/assets/app.js` by the first block, then resolves to `/var/www/cut/public/assets/app.js` by the `root` and `try_files` directives.

Comment: Yeah, working. But have a problem with `/cut` : this call make a redirection and I get `/cut/public` as URI. Perhaps I need to remove it before call the PHP backend ?

Comment: Ahhh Found ! I add `/?` in `^~ /cut` : `rewrite ^/cut/?(.*)$ /cut/public/$1 last;` and it works... Then answer accepted, @Richard Smith

Comment: You may have issues with other bare directories, with `nginx` adding a trailing slash from inside `/cut/public`. But I was just about to suggest adding the `/?` for `/cut`.

Comment: I've tried to put some sub-folder under `/cut/public` and It works perfectly with index, static files and php files.

Comment: NEsted location helps me. thanks=